# How to group_by xtab's dimnames and mutate based on values in table?

Tags: r, dplyr, magrittr

Let's say I have an xtab (built as the last step in a dplyr pipeline) that looks like this:

```
        treatPer
treatGrp          0          1
       0        7.2        8.4
       1        6.3        9.1
```

You can build it with...

```
.R > dput(x)
structure(c(7.2, 6.3, 8.4, 9.1), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), .Dimnames = 
structure(list(treatGrp = c("0", "1"), treatPer = c("0", 
"1")), .Names = c("treatGrp", "treatPer")), class = c("xtabs", 
"table"), call = xtabs(formula = x/1000 ~ treatGrp + treatPer, 
    data = .))
```

What I want to do is continue this pipeline, but I don't know how to refer to the group names or their values.  Eg, this doesn't work:

```
... %>%
xtabs(x/1000 ~ treatGrp + treatPer, data = .) %>% 
  group_by(attr(x, 'dimnames')$treatGrp)

Error in UseMethod("group_by_") : 
  no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "c('xtabs', 'table')"
```

And even if it did, I wouldn't know how to refer to the values in the table in order to `mutate` a new column like `percentagePointChange` (ie `mutate(ppCh = (value - lag(value))/lag(value))`)

Any suggestions?

(I suppose I could `data.frame(x)` and then do the calcs and reapply the `xtab` but since I've put this up I'll see if anyone has a recco based on the above...)

Comment: I get an error when I try to run your `structure` code, because the data `.` isn't found. I can delete the formula and get an object of classes xtabs and table

Answer (score 0):

You get an error because `group_by` works on data frames, and you have a table. All you need to do is coerce the table to something `group_by` can work with, using your choice of `as.data.frame`, `as_data_frame`, `as_tibble`, or probably some others out there. Each of these will work in a pipeline, so you can do whatever calculations you have, create the xtab, pipe that into `as_data_frame`, and then keep working.

Like I said in my comment earlier, I couldn't read the data with the formula included, because that refers back to the data frame above it in the pipeline.

```r
library(tidyverse)

xtab <- structure(c(7.2, 6.3, 8.4, 9.1), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), .Dimnames = 
                    structure(list(treatGrp = c("0", "1"), treatPer = c("0", "1")), 
                    .Names = c("treatGrp", "treatPer")), class = c("xtabs", "table"))
```

Converting with `as_data_frame` gets you this:

```r
as_data_frame(xtab)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>   treatGrp treatPer     n
#>   <chr>    <chr>    <dbl>
#> 1 0        0          7.2
#> 2 1        0          6.3
#> 3 0        1          8.4
#> 4 1        1          9.1
```

You can then do normal operations on it, using `group_by` and whatever else. Here's one example:

```r
as_data_frame(xtab) %>%
  group_by(treatGrp) %>%
  summarise(avg_n = mean(n))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   treatGrp avg_n
#>   <chr>    <dbl>
#> 1 0          7.8
#> 2 1          7.7
```

Or to build a whole pipeline based on an example in the `xtabs` docs:

```r
library(tidyverse)

as_data_frame(UCBAdmissions) %>%
  xtabs(n ~ Gender + Admit, data = .) %>%
  as_data_frame() %>%
  group_by(Gender) %>%
  mutate(rate = n / sum(n))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#> # Groups:   Gender [2]
#>   Gender Admit        n  rate
#>   <chr>  <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 Female Admitted   557 0.304
#> 2 Male   Admitted  1198 0.445
#> 3 Female Rejected  1278 0.696
#> 4 Male   Rejected  1493 0.555
```